# How to select specific sets or sturture from a file, if struture contains specific string?

Tags: awk, grep

I want to extract the sets with having specific string, for example:

file `abc.txt` contains

```
abc 123
abcd 1234
abcde 12345

abc 123
abcd 123
abcde 12345

abc 123
abcd 1234
abcde 12345
```

Now from the above sets it can be observed that in 2nd set 2nd row doesn't have `1234`. So what I want to extract are these sets which have such strings.

```
abc 123
abcd 123
abcde 12345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> awk -v RS=$'\n\n' -v FS=$'\n' -v ORS=$'\n\n' '$2 ~ /123$/ {print}' abc.txt
abc 123
abcd 123
abcde 12345
```

Comment: actually i want to extract those sets which have abcd 123

Comment: As for me there are too many variables are set via `-v`. Would you like to use `BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=ORS="\n\n"}` instead?

Comment: @Sahni There in not a problem to reverse match `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=ORS="\n\n"}$2!~"abcd 123$"' abc.txt`

Comment: @Sahni Or `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=ORS="\n\n"}$2!="abcd 123"' abc.txt` which more correct

Comment: @Hauke thanks a lot, it helped me to save alot of my time, again thanks for your precious time.

Comment: @Costas thanks a lot man for your suggestions, some how they also help me to identify the situation.

Comment: @Hauke ,again thanks in advance, i have one more issue regarding the same question, so do i need to edit it or need to post new one ?

Comment: @Sahni That depends on it how close it is related but hardly anyone will notice a modified old question (I am not sure whether an edit puts an old question on top of the queue). If you make a new question then you should link this one and explain the difference between both.

Answer (score 1):

It is standart procedure for GNU `sed`

```
sed '/abc 123/{:1;$!{N;/\n$/!b1}};/\babcd 123\b/d' abc.txt
```

Or

```
sed '/^$/!{:1;$!{N;/\n$/!b1}};/\babcd 123\b/d' abc.txt
```

if you oriented for empty row, not for 1st (`abc 123`) in block